# libusbdotnet find all similar devices

Tags: c#, usb

I have a custom USB device based on an ATMEL and V-USB. I have the test circuit up an running and everything is working fine.

I have a situation where multiple of these devices will be plugged into one PC. I need to list them all in code. All of the examples only show how to find and connect to one device:

http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/Index.html

According to the docs I need to set up a usbdevicefinder with the Product and Vender IDs and then pass that to FindAll from the UsbRegDeviceList, so here is my code:

```
 public static void GetUSBDevices()
    {
        //Find devices matching the vendor and product ID
        UsbDeviceFinder USBFinder = new UsbDeviceFinder(VENDORID, PRODUCTID);
        //Using the registry create a list of those devices
        UsbRegDeviceList USBRegistryDevices = new UsbRegDeviceList();
        USBRegistryDevices = USBRegistryDevices.FindAll(USBFinder);
    }
```

Please note this is a class method and it is not complete yet. I am stepping through the code with the debugger and examining the internals of USBRegistryDevices after the last line executes and it keeps getting a count of 0. VENDORID, PRODUCTID are constants defined in code.

Am I implementing the code incorrectly?

Comment: PS there is a another method I could do: http://libusbdotnet.sourceforge.net/V2/Index.html by manually iterating through all the devices and looking for matching PIDs/VIDs, but this is not the elegant method.

Comment: Found a workaround. I am using UsbRegDeviceList USBRegistryDevices = UsbDevice.AllDevices.FindAll(USBFinder); instead. Not sure why my first method is not working.